# How to create Histogram using ggplot2 that uses 2 variables (year and income) and puts then on x and y axes separately?

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

I am having issues with creating histogram using 2 variables in R. The things is that I need to plot a histogram with 2 variables- year and income, that I take from my dataset. I need to plot the histogram in a way so that year variable will lie on horizontal axis and income variable will lay on y axis. So, the histogram should show income values for each year. How to write code in R for plotting this kind of histogram?

I cannot write the script since the ordinary code for plotting histogram requires only one variable and the frequency is shown for that variable automatically.

Comment: But a histogram is a plot that shows distribution? Are you either thinking about plotting 2 variables on the x-axis showing the [difference in distribution](https://r-charts.com/distribution/histogram-group-ggplot2/), or perhaps a [boxplot?](https://r-charts.com/distribution/box-plot-ggplot2/)

Comment: It's when one variable should be on x-axis, and the other one should be on y-axis.

Comment: That's not a histogram then.

Answer (score 0):

**New Edit**
I have focused on the tags of this post and realized only later, that you are interested in `ggplot`. Please, see at the end.

---

As a start for your further study I would like to create an artificial **DF** which I believe resembles the one you might have in mind.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(
  year = sample(2000:2001, replace = T, 100),
  income = rnorm(100, mean = 100000, sd=1000)
)
```

It is a **DF** with 2 variables - `year` and `income`.
You can easily make a *histogram* of `income` for each year (there are 2 years only) by. You will recognize that `hist` takes the variable `income` breaks it up in `bins` and counts the numbers of entries in each `bin`. Here it is done for the years separately.

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(df$income[df$year == 2000], main = "2000", xlab="", ylim = c(0,14))
hist(df$income[df$year == 2001], main = "2001", xlab="", ylim = c(0,14))
```

[image]

As you want to have `year` on the x-axis I have added up all the incomes for each year and made a `barplot`. This is NOT a histogram.

```r
ddf <- df |> 
  group_by(year) |> 
  summarise(income = sum(income)) 

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
barplot(income~year, data = ddf)
```

[image]

---

**GGPLOT**

```
ggplot(df, aes(income, fill = factor(year))) +
  geom_histogram(color = "white")+
  facet_wrap(~year, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(year), income,fill = factor(year))) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

You will find useful information about graphics in **R** [here](https://r-graphics.org/recipe-quick-histogram).